# Update user profile in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I am trying to update some user profile data as follows:

To update profile in routes.php

```
Route::get('/profile/update/{id}', [
        'as' => 'user.edit',
        'uses' => 'UserController@edit'
    ]);
```

In my UserController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
      $user = User::findOrFail($id);

      return view('user/edit', compact('user'));
}
```

My action in edit.blade.php

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['action' => ['UserController@update', 'id' => $user->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('name', $user->name, [
                            'class' => 'form-control'
                        ]) !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('email', 'E-mail') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('email', $user->email, [
                            'class' => 'form-control'
                        ]) !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('phone', 'Phone') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('phone', $user->phone, [
                            'class' => 'form-control'
                        ]) !!}
                    </div>

                    <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Profile</button></p>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

The route for update:

```
Route::put('/profile/update/{id}', [
        'as' => 'user.update',
        'uses' => 'UserController@update'
    ]);
```

And the function in the UserController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->update([
            $request->input('name'),
            $request->input('email'),
            $request->input('phone')
        ]);

        return Redirect::route('user.profile');
    }
```

After updating the field I want (for example the phone), it simply returns to the profile screen, but does not update it in the database. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you made those attributes fillable in your User model?

Comment: Yes. By default it comes like this, but I modified it so that it stays that way, and the result is the same.                                                                         protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'phone'];

Comment: you are not assign this values to their correct columns. it must be `$user->column = 'value';` since you are using a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you are saving the data. try this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->name=$request->input('name');
        $user->email=$request->input('email');
        $user->phone=$request->input('phone');

        $user->save();
        return Redirect::route('user.profile');
    }
```

Comment: Yes ! That´s it ! Why $user->update() didn´t work ??

Comment: @jandro935 because you are using a model

Comment: @NewbeeDev Thanks for the info !!

Answer (score 0):

Trying this: the keys should be the field names in the database and make sure to set them as `$fillable` in the Model

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone
        ]);

        return Redirect::route('user.profile');
    }
```

Add in User model

```
protected $fillable=['name','email','phone'];
```

Comment: if you are using create or update method, don't forget make $fillable fields in User model.

Answer (score 0):

if the request has parameters named the same as your model, you can do this:

`$user->update($request->all());`

your model properties that you want to update should be ranked as fillable in your model

`protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];`

Answer (score 0):

You should update your 'update' method:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) 
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($request->only(['name', 'email', 'phone']));

    return Redirect::route('user.profile');
}
```